# Is there any difference between using the Up button and using Intent to go Up one activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-toolbar

I am creating custom `Toolbar` for my activities, and I need to have an 'Up' button to go back to the parent activity. I got it working on one of the activities, but unfortunately, the 'Up' button is not visible(because it is  black in colour and the `Toolbar` is also black), but it works, i.e. tapping on that area takes me back to the parent activity.

When changing between different `NoActionBar` themes didn't work, I tried creating a custom `Toolbar` with an `ImageView` as the Up button, but I used `Intent` to switch back to the parent activity this time. It works fine, and I am thinking of using this approach throughout.

**So, if there any difference between using `Intent` to switch back to the parent Activity V/S using the Up button on the `Toolbar` ?**

Here is the Java code for the activity which doesn't have a visible Up Button:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ll_home);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // Important, Required to hide the default title
    });
```

And here is its XML code

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the Java code for the Activity having a Toolbar with UpButton as an ImageView (using Intent to go back to parent Activity)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.camera_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ImageView upButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_activity_up_button);
        upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),NavDrawerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

And the corresponding XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/camera_toolbar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:id="@+id/camera_activity_up_button"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="00:00:00"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:id="@+id/wmb_toolbar_title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_switch_camera_white_24dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you should add the code you tried, so we can check for errors or similar

Comment: Have you tried using `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`?

Comment: Sure, right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Intent will create the activity again instead of resuming the activity in its previous state(Unless you use some flags while creating the activity such as activity single top) whereas using back button or up arrow will resume the parent/previous activity without violating the activity lifecycle. please read the activity life cycle documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Update :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_your);
        Toolbar actionbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
        if (null != actionbar) {
            actionbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.arrow_icon);

            actionbar.setTitle(R.string.title_activity);
            actionbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(yourActivity.this);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks SaravInfern, can you tell me what possibly is causing the upButton not being displayed ? (ie being black in colour on black Toolbar). The theme I am specifying in Manifest is @style/AppTheme.NoActionBar

Comment: Thanks, that works. I was following the guide on CodePath and developer.android.com, and this was the best I could do.